# Automate Login in Shell Script

Tags: macos, shell, scripting, terminal

I want to create an automate login for github push to repository script in mac terminal. But I met some problem with login issue, like it will ask for username and password, so what command that can automatically insert username when it ask for username same with password?
I found 'expect' command in Linux, but the way of using is different in Mac terminal.

```
Lunayos-MacBook-Pro:SuperDeals-iPhone Lunayo$ git push origin
Everything up-to-date
Lunayos-MacBook-Pro:SuperDeals-iPhone Lunayo$ git push upstream
Username:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer to GitHub's excellent help articles:

- [Set Up Git](http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/)
- [SSH key passphrases](http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/)
- [Remotes](http://help.github.com/remotes/)

You need to either generate an SSH key with no passphrase (or start ssh-agent before you use your script if you would like to use a passphrase); otherwise, OpenSSH will ask for a password or passphrase.

Also ensure that your remote URL looks like `ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git` or `git@github.com:user/repo.git`. Specifically, the `git@` part tells Git and OpenSSH that you want to make the SSH connection using the username `git` (which is correct for all GitHub repositories).

Comment: why using the ssh, it doesn't required username and password anymore? and so it is not possible for automate login in shell if required?